# How to limit the types of audits in Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I'm attempting my first Hibernate Envers implementation. I've got all my @Audited tags in place and I'm generating the DDL to create the audit tables.

From what I've read, the audit tables will get a record each time the audited table gets a new record, a record changes or a record is deleted.

For my implementation, I only really care about changes and since I've read that there are performance hits to auditing, I'd like to turn off what I don't need.

I've had a hard time finding information on this. The only thing that came close said that I would need to turn off all the Envers listeners and re-implement them myself, having the ones I don't want do nothing.

This seems like a lot of work and I'm already in uncharted territory. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? Failing that, does anyone have some code they can share showing how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: I understand your performance concerns, but given your implementation; have you profiled and determined whether there is any merit to your concern?  Envers is used by a number of large private organizations managing millions of rows with little or no overhead.   Perhaps you can elaborate more specifically on your use case of concern and I'll be happy to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is no there isn't.

The only toggle option that is available that comes close is to tell Envers whether it should audit all column data in the `DEL` revision type rows or not.  The default behavior is not to include all column values when an entity is deleted; however there are cases where storing this information can be highly useful.

Furthermore, this isn't just a simple case of preventing the registration of a specific Envers listener nor is it as simple as recoding a specific listener.

Lets look at some use cases

```
// Fetch the parent
Parent parent = entityManager.find( Parent.class, parentId );

// Add a new child entity to parent
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
Child child = new Child( "Naros" );
child.setParent( parent );
parent.getChildren().add( child );
entityManager.persist( child );
entityManager.merge( parent );    
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

// Update a child entity 
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
child.setName( "Naros2" );
entityManager.merge( child );
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

// Remove child entities from parent
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
parent.getChildren().forEach( c -> c.setParent( null ) );
parent.getChildren().clear();
entityManager.merge( parent );
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

In all `3` cases above, the `Parent` entity will be audited with a `MOD` revised entry that describes that it was modified at a specific time with a given revision number.

Similarly the first scenario will contain an `ADD` revised entry for the `Child` when it was added to the parent's collection.  This would include the same revision number as the first revision of the `Parent`.

The second scenario will contain an `MOD` revised entry for the `Child` when it was modified.  Depending on the type of the collection in the parent, whether the changes you made influence the order of the collection, its possible that a `MOD` will be triggered for the `Parent` entity as well.

The last scenario will contain a `DEL` revised entry for the `Child` when it is removed from the collection and a `MOD` because the parent's state was modified.

Can this type of behavior be disabled, yes.  But the problem with doing that is you loose some really valuable functionality.

For example, the `Parent` would only contain audit rows for when you actually modified a property of `Parent` and not when you modify any collection properties that are associated to it.  That means in a simple example, `Parent` would only have 1 audit row, the `ADD` when it was inserted.

But what if you need to know the actual state of `Parent` at each revised step after the changes to the children collection?  Well, you can't.

You haven't given any details as to why performance would really be a problem here, so I cannot necessarily touch on that with specifics.

But trying to turn off aspects of Envers can and likely will have negative implications from an audit perspective if you do.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I had read about performance issues which made sense to me if the application is duplicating classes and persisting them all the time. However, if you say it isn't that much of hit, I'm OK with it.

Comment: I'm migrating from another system which also had auditing but only on changes. I had planned to migrate the changes into the audit tables manually. Is this advisable? Would you create the change records only or should I create the oldest revision as an add record?

Comment: If you have a clear understanding of the audit table schema and how the revision numbers work, etc then you can certainly migrate your old audit history to the Envers schema.  You'd just make the first change entry from the legacy system as an `ADD` and others `MOD`.  Of course if all that legacy information isn't important, you can certainly migrate just the last entry as the `ADD` if you wish (assuming that the last legacy change = current record snapshot).